# Sending emails in Redmine with Windows and WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, email, gmail, redmine

This is my first installation of Redmine and I am not a Ruby or Rails developer. Installed Redmine on Windows 8.1 and I need it to send e-mail notifications using a (free) Gmail account.

When I try to "Send a test email" I always get the same error:

```
An error occurred while sending mail (execution expired)
```

I have followed the instructions here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall and then the email configuration here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration

I installed the RailsInstaller (http://railsinstaller.org/) with Ruby 2.1 (because I had problems with nokogiri and Ruby 2.2) and Rails 4.2. The version of Redmine is 3.2.1.

Edited configuration.yml with this:

```
...
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration
  # See the examples below and the Rails guide for more configuration options:
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.gmail.com" 
      port: 587
      domain: "smtp.gmail.com" 
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "xxxxx@gmail.com" 
      password: "xxxxx" 
...
```

I tried many variations like putting this section in the "production" part of the file, removing everything else in the file, using port 465, using authentication :login, removing or adding quotes, ... I also checked that there are spaces everywhere and not tabs.

My Gmail account has POP3 and IMAP enabled.

I have the Windows firewall disabled. I disabled also IPv6 but this doesn't fix the problem.

I am executing Redmine with this command:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\redmine-3.2.1>bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```

Looking at the code, Redmine uses ActionMailer from Ruby on Rails.

- Is it possible to send e-mails through Gmail using my environment (Windows 8.1, Ruby 2.1, Rails 4.2, WEBrick)?

  - I don't have `sendmail` or anything like that installed
- In case it is possible, how can I debug my problem?

Comment: First take a look at C:\RailsInstaller\redmine-3.2.1\log

Comment: I didn't find much in the log apart from "Email delivery error: execution expired". After installing Redmine in an Ubuntu VM (using postfix for the email) and facing the same problem again, I tried 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 587' and 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 465' and I get the timeout as well. So I believe that my company's firewall is blocking the port. I will keep investigating in that direction.